# How to find bases for a subspace defined by an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you find the bases for

$W_1 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) \in F^5: a_1 - a_3 - a_4 = 0 \}$ and $W_2 = \{ (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) \in F^5: a_2 = a_3 = a_4$ and $a_1+a_5 = 0 \}$ ?

Would the basis for $W_1$ be $\{ (1 \,0 \, 1 \, 0 \, 0), (1 \, 0 \, 0 \, 1 \, 0) \}$ and $dim(W_1) = 2$?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is one linear restriction on the elements of $W_1$, it follows that $\dim W_1=4$. One basis would be $$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{r}1\\0\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r}0\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r}0\\0\\1\\-1\\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)\right\}.$$

As for $W_2$, there are three linear restrictions, so that $\dim W_2=2$ and a basis would be
$$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{r}1\\0\\0\\0\\-1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r}0\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This question appears in section 1.6 of Linear Algebra, but the following solution will use techniques from chapter 2 (dimension theorem), chapter 3 (connection between rank of linear transformation and matrix), and chapter 6 (orthogonality of row space and null space).

For the subspace $W_{1},$ we encode the linear constraint $a_{1}-a_{3}-a_{4}=0$ in the following matrix:
$$A_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
since the solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system:
$$A_{1} \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{4} \\ a_{5} \end{pmatrix} = 0$$
satisfies the constraint. Now, we identify the solution set as the null space $N(A_{1}),$ then we apply the dimension theorem ($dim(N(A_{1})) = nullity(A_{1}) = dim(F^{5}) - rank(A_{1})$). Thus, the problem is to find a subset of the null space with exactly $4$ linearly independent vectors.

To obtain this subset, we identify the $(A_{1})_{1,1} = 1$ entry as the pivot variable. Next, we identify the $(A_{1})_{1,2} = 0, (A_{1})_{1,3} = -1, (A_{1})_{1,4} = -1,$ and $(A_{1})_{1,5} = 0$ entries as the free variables. Then, we obtain a solution
$$\{ (0,1,0,0,0), (1,0,1,0,0), (1,0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,0,1)\},$$
where we have expressed the vectors as $5$-tuples.

Similarly, for the subspace $W_{2},$ we encode the linear constraints $a_{1}+a_{5}=0,$ $a_{2}=a_{3},$ and $a_{3}=a_{4}$ in the following matrix:
$$A_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \phantom{-} 0 & \phantom{-} 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & \phantom{-} 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \phantom{-} 1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
since the solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system:
$$A_{2} \begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{4} \\ a_{5} \end{pmatrix} = 0$$
satisfies the constraints. Now, we identify the solution set as the null space $N(A_{2}),$ then we apply the dimension theorem ($dim(N(A_{2})) = nullity(A_{2}) = dim(F^{5}) - rank(A_{2})$). Thus, the problem is to find a subset of the null space with exactly $2$ linearly independent vectors.

In this case, we obtain
$$\{ (0,1,1,1,0), (-1,0,0,0,1)\},$$
where we have expressed the vectors as $5$-tuples.